# Michael Hartl Double Flash Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been following the Michael Hartl guide and the only error that I see (but the system doesn't catch), is that every time there is a flash like in the image below, the alert shows up twice as opposed to once. I've spent way too long troubleshooting this. Where would I edit the flash behavior.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ddb2.jpg

Here is my User Controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

 before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
 before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
 before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy


  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)    # Not the final implementation!
    if @user.save
      UserMailer.account_activation(@user).deliver_now
      flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User deleted"
    redirect_to users_url
  end


  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
       flash[:success] = "Profile Updated"
       redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

    private

   def user_params
          params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                       :password_confirmation)
   end

  #Before filters

  def logged_in_user
    unless logged_in?
      store_location
      flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
      redirect_to login_url

    end
  end

 # Confirms an admin user.
    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
    end

 # Confirms the correct user.
    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
     redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

end
```

My Application Layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all',
    'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/r29/html5.min.js">
      </script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
     <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
     <%= content_tag(:div, message, class: "alert alert-#{message_type}") %>
        <div class="alert alert-<%= message_type %>"><%= message %></div>
      <% end %>
      <%= yield %>
    <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
    <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add three bits of code to your question please: (1) the code for the controller where you're setting the flash, (2) the layout code and (3) the view code.

Comment: @smathy I've added the code, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change...

```
<% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
  <%= content_tag(:div, message, class: "alert alert-#{message_type}") %>
  <div class="alert alert-<%= message_type %>"><%= message %></div>
<% end %>
```

to...

```
  <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
    <%= content_tag(:div, message, class: "alert alert-#{message_type}") %>
  <% end %>
```

The flash behavior isn't the issue.  You're rendering error messages twice because you're duplicating the error message div in your `flash.each do ...` block.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's very clear, look at your loop:

```
<% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
  <%= content_tag(:div, message, class: "alert alert-#{message_type}") %>
  <div class="alert alert-<%= message_type %>"><%= message %></div>
<% end %>
```

You're outputting two `div`s per loop (ie. per flash message), one using the `content_tag` helper, and one using the `<div` literal text.  Remove one of them.